# Call function in another ViewController (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, xcode-storyboard

How can I communicate with another View Controller on Xcode Storyboards in any possible way?

Given the principle of encapsulation, the preferred way seems to be to call a function in the other ViewController.

(failed) ideas:

- Using self.storyboard to [instantiate a Controller](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstoryboard/1426549-instantiatecontroller) with the specified Identifier, casting it to the correct View Controller subclass
- instantiating the view controller with `let c = specialViewController()` [doesn't work because the instance's views haven't loaded]
- connecting an IBOutlet to another NSViewController subclass [this one should work but doesn't]

Note: iOS solutions often are not the same as MacOS solutions

First failed idea code:

```
let spec_ref = self.storyboard!.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "specialSettings") as! SpecialSettings
 spec_ref.save_spec_settings();
```

save_spec_function:
[image]

The spec_ref still cannot access IBOutlets in the other ViewController on the Storyboard, so it must not be the correct instance.

Comment: Note: iOS solutions often are in fact the same as MacOS solutions when writing code in Swift.  You are just not doing it right and not showing a single line of code to make your point.

Comment: Are you aware that UIKit, the iOS user interface, is completely different from AppKit, the MacOS user interface? I gather that you are an iOS developer.

Comment: Show the relevant code for your first idea -- that seems like the one that is most-likely appropriate for your situation, but you haven't given any code to diagnose.

Comment: I have several dozen desktop applications developed for macOS that are sold at Mac App Store if that's what you are asking.  No, I don't use Catalyst although I occasionally develop iOS apps with UIKit.

Comment: @jnpdx okay I added it including the error code in an image.

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to access the `IBOutlet`s on the new view controller (is that what `popup1` is?)? Seems like you probably need some re-architecting. Shouldn't you know through a different method what `indexOfSelectedItem` will be upon initialization of the view controller? In general, it's pretty unclear what that code is supposed to do. It'd be ideal to include a [mre]

Comment: Or, set a couple of properties you *do* have access to (not the IBOutlets, which haven't been loaded) and then do any calculations based on those in `viewDidLoad`. Right now, there doesn't seem to be an obvious reason to not just use `viewDidLoad` to call `save_spec_settings`

Comment: I do not know what popup menu item the user will pick. hence why I am calling indexOfSelectedItem. 

But your comment gave me an idea that bypasses the question - have an IBAction on popup menu selection, and in that IBAction set a global property for the index of selected item which can then be accessed from another View Controller.

Comment: I created a minimal reproducible Xcode project but don't know how to share it... If anyone would like to see it let me know. 
I could use the solution in my above comment but that would use a bit more memory.

Comment: You should probably have a state storage solution that isn’t owned by a single view controller. Something that could get passed from VC to VC, though. Maybe that’s what you’re alluding to in your last comment.

Comment: Please post your example to GitHub.

Comment: As for your main question: you can talk to another view controller by getting a reference to it by way of the window that contains it, but this seems a bad idea; you should use bindings to a more central value.

Comment: Ok here's the link to the github: https://github.com/dominikwrona/viewcontroller_test

Comment: Cool but your example has only one view controller so what exactly are we talking about?

Comment: My bad I uploaded the wrong one, the correct project is now uploaded.

Comment: Your example doesn't really seem to illustrate the problem. You're trying to access an `IBOutlet`, which should be set from some sort of state, *immediately* after instantiation of the view controller, when you would *already know* the state of it. If you did it later, the `IBOutlet` would be set, and there wouldn't be a problem. As has been suggested, you should rethink your architecture to encapsulate your state in a way that isn't owned by a single view controller.

Comment: How are the view controllers related?

Comment: You can see in the github file - they are both tabs under a NSTabViewController.

Comment: The tab view controller can reach its tab items. Move the save function to the tab view controller and connect the Save button to the First Responder. Ask the view controller of the second tab view item (`tabViewItems[1].viewController as? SecondController`) for the selected popup item.